# Help configure `mimeapps.list` to open gedit instead of gnome-text-editor?

Tags: gedit, mime-type, 23.04, gnome-text-editor

On Ubuntu 23.04, I have installed Gedit alongside the default Text Editor (gnome-text-editor).

I want to keep gnome-text-editor, but I would like most text files to open in gedit.

I have added the following to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, but it does not work-- if I click on a `*.txt` file in Nautilus, it still opens in gnome-text-editor. What am I doing wrong in the following file?

```
# Separate *.desktop files with a ";"

[Default Applications]
application/octet-stream=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
application/xml=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
application/json=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-patch=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
application/javascript=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-csrc=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/markdown=org.gnome.gedit.desktop

[Added Associations]
application/octet-stream=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
application/xml=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
application/json=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-patch=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
application/javascript=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-csrc=org.gnome.gedit.desktop

# Override R Studio mime types listed in /usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop
text/x-tex=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-markdown=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/html=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/css=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/javascript=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-chdr=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-csrc=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-c++hdr=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-c++src=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/markdown=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was missing a very important mapping:

```
text/plain=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
```

This took care of opening most text files in Gedit.

I also added a couple of other mappings (to open XML and Python files in Gedit):

```
application/x-shellscript=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
text/x-python3=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
```